# What design is this?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have been unable to look for the powerpoint format shown below. I am using powerpoint 2016 and was hoping someone could let me know

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you *sure* that it's a powerpoint template and not a custom job?

Comment: @שelz It's not a custom job, if you reverse image search it you can find many examples of it being used.

Comment: sorry how do i "reverse image seach" ? It would be great if I can find a non-pdf version

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's called "Capital".

https://notes.indezine.com/2018/05/capital-powerpoint-theme-and-template.html

[image]